# Why does automatic failover break when running both HA HDFS and MR1?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am re-configuring a Hadoop cluster to use the High Availability (HA) features for both the shared filesystem and the MR1 jobtracker.

It seems I can't get the automatic failover features for both to work at the same time.  Instead one of the services is stuck with both (all) daemons stuck in standby.

How do I get automatic failover to work for all my HA services?

I'm using:

- Cloudera CDH 4.5.0
- JDK 7
- Ubuntu 12.04
- ...without the Cloudera Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namenode and jobtracker share a similar HA implementation, to the degree that they both extend the same base class.  They both use a backing zookeeper cluster to decide which available node is active.

The location used in zookeeper is constructed by appending the failover group name (i.e. the values given in `dfs.nameservices` and `mapred.job.tracker`) to a configurable prefix.

For both services the configurable prefix is `/hadoop-ha` by default.

This means if the two services are configured with the same failover group name (say, `my-application`) then the final zookeeper paths used by the two services will collide.  If they in fact use the same zookeeper cluster, one service will not get a zookeeper node and have broken automatic failover.

The solution is to avoid the collision.  The easiest way is to ensure that `mapred.job.tracker` in `mapred-site.xml` and `dfs.nameservices` in `hdfs-site.xml` do not contain common values.

One might also attempt to configure the `/hadoop-ha` prefix on a per-service basis.  It is controlled by the `ha.zookeeper.parent-znode` configuration property.

For example, in `hdfs-site.xml` one might have:

```
<property>
  <name>ha.zookeeper.parent-znode</name>
  <value>/hdfs-ha</value>
</property>
```

...while `mapred-site.xml` contains:

```
<property>
  <name>ha.zookeeper.parent-znode</name>
  <value>/mapred-ha</value>
</property>
```

**However**, be aware that in this configuration `hdfs-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` can't be loaded at the same time: the value of one key will clobber the other.

Either way the zookeeper paths will have changed, requiring the respective `-formatZK` commands to be re-run.